# Web Font VarelaRound

Tags: discussion, design

I love the web font this site is using. I really felt in love with it. It seems to be some sort of VarelaRound web-font but I couldn't find the real web font with *italic* and **bold** style.
Was that paid or free?
If free, where could I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was created by [Joe Prince](http://cargocollective.com/admixdesigns), and it's part of the [Google Web Fonts collection](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Varela+Round). The typeface doesn't have an italic version, just the normal face. It's being rendered in obliques on the fly by the browser. If you create an HTML file with the following, you'll see it in action:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Varela Round Test</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <p style="font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;">Test <em>test</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh yes. `<em>` and `<strong>`, you are right. I was using `<b>` and `<i>` and couldn't see the difference. EM and STRONG are rendered by the browser every time, even if there's no such a style for that font. How could I forget? Thanks.